# ARM Assembler - Loop getting stuck

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, arm

I'm currently writing some basic ARM assembler. The idea is to control a theoretical furnace and it's cooling/heating system on the LPC2378 development board with an application board attached.

I'm getting there as far as recognising input from the devices is concerned. However, i'm having trouble getting my loop right and I was hoping you guys may be able to point out why my loop is getting stuck, and even after button 1 has been pressed, the fan is not turning on. I previously had the fan working, but when I started trying to control the fan by the temperature of the heater it does not seem to ever start up, and the heater stays on, getting hotter and hotter without the fan to cool it down.

I'm guessing it could come down to the way i'm reading the temperature from the ADC controller.

Please don't hesitate to ask if you need any more information to answer the question.

```
;=========================================================================
; MotorControl_1
;
; BUT1 turns motor ON and BUT2 turns motor OFF
;
; No interrupt support (except for Reset) - as simple as it gets!
;
; WDH, November 2008
;==========================================================================

; Set-up interrupt vectors and stack support
$ LPC2378InterruptVectors.s

; After a reset exception, execution starts here - the processor is in ARM
; mode and supervisor state with interrupts disabled

    SECTION .text:CODE:NOROOT(2)

    REQUIRE __vector  ; Forces reference to this symbol - required by linker

    ARM

; __iar_program_start - defined start symbol.
__iar_program_start:

; Include lpc2378 IO register definitions
#include "iolpc2378.h"

; Include Olimex LPC-2378-STK IO definitions
#include "OlimexLPC2378BoardDefs.h"

; Main entry point - required by debugger

;=========================================================================
; main starts here
;=========================================================================
main

;=========================================================================
; Stack setup
;
; Stack pointer (r13 or SP) is assigned the highest address in a 32kB
; section of on-chip SRAM - assumes a FULL descending stack convention
;=========================================================================

    ldr r13, = 0x40008000
    ldr r2, = 0x000050    ;Load the delay value
    ldr r3, = 0x028       ;Start set point at 40
    ldr r4, = 0x000       ;Start temp difference as 0
;        ldr r6, = 0x0f        ;Temp High Value (15)
;        ldr r7, = -0xF        ;Set r7 to -15.   

; Initialise IO
  BL InitialiseARM_IO
  BL InitialiseApplicationsBoard_IO

; Initialise the devices and display
  BL FanOff
  BL errorLedOff
  BL systemLedOff
  BL heaterOff


LoopStart

  BL WaitBUT1
  BL heaterOn
  BL systemLedOn
  BL readTemp
  BL checkTemp
  CMP r0, #5
  BGT errorVal
  SUBS r7, r6, r4 ;Performs r7 = r6 - r4 and sets condition register
  BLT LoopStart ;Branches to label_bar if r7 < 0 (in which case r6 < r4)
  BGT heaterOff
  BGT errorLedOn
  BGT FanOn
  BGT LoopStart
  BL WaitBUT2
  BL FanOff
  BL errorLedOff
  BL systemLedOff
  BL heaterOff

        B LoopStart


  ;=========================================================================
  ; InitialiseARM_IO
  ;
  ; Initialise the ARM interface, as follows:
  ;
  ; Port0(13..14} GPIO Output to on-board LEDs
  ;    bit 13:      USB_LINK LED
  ;    bit 14:      USB_CONNECT LED
  ; Port0{18,29} GPIO Input from BUT1 and BUT2
  ;    bit 18:      BUT2 pressbutton input
  ;    bit 29:      BUT1 pressbutton input
  ; Port1{18,19} GPIO Inputs from joystick UP and DOWN
  ;    bit 18:      UP joystick inout
  ;    bit 19:      DOWN joystick input
  ;=========================================================================
  InitialiseARM_IO

  ; Define data direction for LEDs - the LEDs are connected
  ; to P0.13 and P0.14

  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}   ; Push r0, r5 and LR

  ;LEDs on ARM board:
  ; Assign GPIO on P0.13 and P0.14
  LDR R5, =PINSEL0         ; Address of PINSEL0
  LDR R0, [R5]             ; Read current PINSEL0
  BIC R0, R0, #0x3C000000  ; Clear bits 26..29
  STR R0, [R5]             ; Put back in PINSEL0

  ; Configure output for P0.13 and P0.14
  LDR R5, =IO0DIR          ; Address of IO0DIR
  LDR R0, [R5]             ; Read current IO0DIR
  ORR R0, R0, #0x6000      ; Set bits 13 and 14 - for P0.13 and P0.14
  STR R0, [R5]             ; Put back in IO0DIR

  ; Switches and Joystick inputs on ARM board
  ; Assign GPIO on P0.18 and P0.29
  LDR R5, =PINSEL1         ; Address of PINSEL1
  LDR R0, [R5]             ; Read current PINSEL1
  BIC R0, R0, #0x30        ; Clear bits 4..5
  BIC R0, R0, #0x0c000000  ; Clear bits 26..27
  STR R0, [R5]             ; Put back in PINSEL0

  ; Configure input for P0.18 and P0.29
  LDR R5, =IO0DIR          ; Address of IO0DIR
  LDR R0, [R5]             ; Read current IO0DIR
  BIC R0, R0, #0x20000000  ; Clear bits 18 and 29 - for P0.18 and P0.29
  BIC R0, R0, #0x00040000
  STR R0, [R5]             ; Put back in IO0DIR

  ; Assign GPIO on P1.18 and P1.19
  LDR R5, =PINSEL3         ; Address of PINSEL3
  LDR R0, [R5]             ; Read current PINSEL3
  BIC R0, R0, #0xF0        ; Clear bits 4..7
  STR R0, [R5]             ; Put back in PINSEL3

  ; Configure input for P1.18 and P1.19
  LDR R5, =IO1DIR          ; Address of IO1DIR
  LDR R0, [R5]             ; Read current IO1DIR
  BIC R0, R0, #0xc0000     ; Clear bits 18 and 19 - for P1.18 and P1.19
  STR R0, [R5]             ; Put back in IO1DIR

  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}   ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14              ; Put link register back into PC



  ;=========================================================================
  ; InitialiseApplicationsBoard_IO
  ;
  ; Initialise the interface to the Applications Board, as follows:
  ;
  ; Port4{0..7} GPIO Output to LEDs, Motor and Heater
  ;    bits 0..4:   Temperature error LED indicators
  ;    bit 5:       Heater control
  ;    bits 6..7:   Motor control
  ; Port4(8..15} GPIO Input from ADC
  ;    bits 8..15:  Inputs from Application Board ADC
  ;
  ;=========================================================================
  InitialiseApplicationsBoard_IO

  ; Define data direction for LEDs - the LEDs are connected
  ; to P0.13 and P0.14

  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}   ; Push r0, r5 and LR

  ; Applications Board Interface via Port4
  ; Set FIO4MASK to allow access to all bits
  LDR R5, =FIO4MASK        ; Address of FIO4DIR
  LDR R0, [R5]             ; Read current IO4DIR
  MOV R0, #0x0             ; Clear all bits of FIO4MASK
  STR R0, [R5]             ; Put back in IO4DIR

  ; Configure output for P4.0 to P4.7
  LDR R5, =FIO4DIR         ; Address of FIO4DIR
  LDR R0, [R5]             ; Read current IO4DIR
  ORR R0, R0, #0xFF        ; Set bits 0..7 - for P4.0 and P4.7
  STR R0, [R5]             ; Put back in IO4DIR

  ; Configure input for P4.8 to P4.15
  LDR R5, =FIO4DIR         ; Address of FIO4DIR
  LDR R0, [R5]             ; Read current IO4DIR
  BIC R0, R0, #0xFF00      ; Clear bits 8..15 - for P4.8 and P4.15
  STR R0, [R5]             ; Put back in IO4DIR

  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}   ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14              ; Put link register back into PC




  ;=========================================================================
  ; Wait for BUT1 to be pressed
  ;=========================================================================
  WaitBUT1
  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}   ; Push r0, r5 and LR

  WaitForBUT1Pressed
    ldr r0, = IO0PIN            ; Address of FIO0PIN register 
    ldr r1, [r0]                ; Read FIO0PIN in to r1
    ands r1, r1, # B1_MASK      ; Mask out BUT1
    beq BUT1Pressed             ; Exit LED toggle loop if button is pressed
    B WaitForBUT1Pressed
  BUT1Pressed

  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}   ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14              ; Put link register back into PC


  ;=========================================================================
  ; Wait for BUT2 to be pressed
  ;=========================================================================
  WaitBUT2
  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}   ; Push r0, r5 and LR

  WaitForBUT2Pressed
    ldr r0, = IO0PIN            ; Address of FIO0PIN register 
    ldr r1, [r0]                ; Read FIO0PIN in to r1
    ands r1, r1, # B2_MASK      ; Mask out BUT1
    beq BUT2Pressed             ; Exit LED toggle loop if button is pressed
    B WaitForBUT2Pressed
  BUT2Pressed

  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}   ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14              ; Put link register back into PC


  ;=========================================================================
  ; Turn Fan Motor ON
  ;=========================================================================
  FanOn
  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Push r0, r5 and LR
  LDR R5, =FIO4PIN            ; Address of FIO4PIN
  LDR r0, [r5]                ; Read current Port4
  ORR r0, r0, #0x80
  STR r0, [r5]                ; Output
  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14                 ; Put link register back into PC

  ;=========================================================================
  ; Turn Fan Motor OFF
  ;=========================================================================
  FanOff
  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Push r0, r5 and LR
  LDR R5, =FIO4PIN            ; Address of FIO4PIN
  LDR r0, [r5]                ; Read current Port4
  BIC r0, r0, #0xc0
  STR r0, [r5]                ; Output
  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14                 ; Put link register back into PC
  ;==============================================================================
  ; Turn On Error LED
  ;==============================================================================
  errorLedOn
  STMFD r13!,{r0, r5,r14}
  mov r0, # USB_LINK_LED_MASK
  ldr r5, = IO0CLR
  str r0, [r5]
  LDMFD r13!,{r0, r5, r14}
  mov pc, r14
  ;==============================================================================
  ; Turn Off Error LED
  ;==============================================================================
  errorLedOff
  STMFD r13!,{r0, r5,r14}
  mov r0, # USB_LINK_LED_MASK
  ldr r5, = IO0SET
  str r0, [r5]
  LDMFD r13!,{r0, r5, r14}
  mov pc, r14
  ;==============================================================================
  ; Turn On System LED   
  ;==============================================================================    
  systemLedOn
  STMFD r13!,{r0, r5,r14}
  mov r0, # USB_CONNECT_LED_MASK
  ldr r5, = IO0CLR
  str r0, [r5]
  LDMFD r13!,{r0, r5, r14}
  mov pc, r14
  ;==============================================================================
  ; Turn Off System LED
  ;==============================================================================
  systemLedOff
  STMFD r13!,{r0, r5,r14}
  mov r0, # USB_CONNECT_LED_MASK
  ldr r5, = IO0SET
  str r0, [r5]
  LDMFD r13!,{r0, r5, r14}
  mov pc, r14 
  ;==============================================================================
  ; Turn Heater On
  ;==============================================================================
  heaterOn
  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Push r0, r5 and LR
  LDR R5, =FIO4PIN            ; Address of FIO4PIN
  LDR r0, [r5]                ; Read current Port4
  ORR r0, r0, #0x20
  STR r0, [r5]                ; Output
  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14                 ; Put link register back into PC     
  ;==============================================================================
  ; Turn The Heater Off
  ;==============================================================================
  heaterOff
  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Push r0, r5 and LR
  LDR R5, =FIO4PIN            ; Address of FIO4PIN
  LDR r0, [r5]                ; Read current Port4
  AND r0, r0, #0xDF
  STR r0, [r5]                ; Output
  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14                 ; Put link register back into PC   
  ;==============================================================================
  ; Read Temperature
  ;============================================================================== 
  readTemp
  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Push r0, r5 and LR
  LDR r0, =FIO4PIN
  LDR r1, [r0]
  LSR r1, r1, #8
  AND r1, r1, #0xFF ; r1 now holds the temperature value
  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14                 ; Put link register back into PC
  ;==============================================================================
  ; Implement Counter And Read Temperature
  ;==============================================================================
  checkTemp
  STMFD r13!,{r0, r14}     ; Push PC, r0, Lr
  LSR r1, r1, #8
  LDR r0, [r2]               ; Load delay value in r0.
  SUB r0, r0, #0x01         ; Minus 1 from delay.
  BEQ readTemp             ; Branch if timer counted down.

  errorVal
  STMFD r13!,{r0, r14}     ; Push PC, r0, Lr
  SUB r1, r3, r6           ; Subtract set point from temperature, into r6
  mov pc, r14                 ; Put link register back into PC


            END
```

Comment: Can you use a JTAG or similar debugger to see what is going on?

Comment: That's a pretty big pile of code; which routine specifically do you think is at fault?

Comment: I'm using a JTAG debugger, if you look at LoopStart, it will wait for button 1, then it will put the heater on, and run down to the BGT FanOn but never turn the FanOn, I believe it may be a problem with the SUBS / errorVal, checkTemp or readTemp.

Comment: BLT is a signed less than, is that what you want?  BLT branch if N!=V, unsigned less than you would swap the operands SUBS r7,r4,r6, and then BHI somewhere.  Are r4 and r6 twos complement 32 bit signed values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you've confused BGT (branch if greater-than) with BLGT (branch and link if greater-than). In the middle of your main loop you have this:

```
  BLT LoopStart ;Branches to label_bar if r7 < 0 (in which case r6 < r4)
  BGT heaterOff
  BGT errorLedOn
  BGT FanOn
  BGT LoopStart
```

If the condition is "greater-than", your code will branch to **heaterOff** and then when that function returns, it will exit the code entirely. The functions **errorLedOn** and **FanOn** can never execute.